# Bevy loading assets relative to debug binary instead of project root

Tags: rust, lldb, bevy, bevy-v0.13.0

I'm getting the following error when loading a GLTF model:

`ERROR bevy_asset::server: Path not found: /path/to/project/target/debug/assets/model.glb`

I'm loading the model with

```
commands.spawn(SceneBundle {
            scene: asset_server.load("model.glb#Scene0"),
            ..default()
        },
    });
```

I don't understand why it's trying to load the asset relative to the target folder rather than the project root. [This page](https://bevy-cheatbook.github.io/assets/assetserver.html) says that it should load relative to the root.

> On desktop platforms, it treats asset paths as relative to a folder called assets, that must be placed at one of the following locations:
>
> - Alongside the game's executable file, for distribution
> - In your Cargo project folder, when running your game using cargo during development
>   This is identified by the CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR environment variable

Answer (score 0):

If you're launching your project for debug with LLDB in VSCode, add the following to your launch config. It will ensure that the "root" of the project is set correctly when debugging.

```
"env": {
    "CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR": "${workspaceFolder}"
},
```